# Border Radius using the :first line selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have  the following in my HTML:

```
<p class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text.It is used to display text in web page.</p>
```

In my CSS:

```
.caption:first-line
{ 
background-color:green;
border-radius:4px;
padding:5px 10px;
}
```

Only `background-color` gets applied to the first line and rest of the styling is omitted. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `border-radius` and `padding` are **not** supported properties of the `:first-line` selector.

The following quote is taken from the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line):

> Only a small subset of all CSS properties can be used inside a
>   declaration block of a CSS ruleset containing a selector using the
>   `::first-line` pseudo-element:
>
> all font-related properties: `font`, `font-style`, `font-variant`,
>   `font-weight`, `font-size`, `line-height` and `font-family`.
>
> The `color` property,
>   all `background`-related properties: `background-color`, `background-image`,
>   `background-position`, `background-repeat`, `background-size`, and
>   `background-attachment`, `word-spacing`, `letter-spacing`, `text-decoration`,
>   `text-transform`, and `line-height`.

Answer (score 2):

From [Selectors Level 3, 5.12.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-line-pseudo):

> The :first-line pseudo-element is similar to an inline-level element, but with certain restrictions. The following properties apply to a :first-line pseudo-element: font properties, color property, background properties, 'word-spacing', 'letter-spacing', 'text-decoration', 'text-transform', and 'line-height'. UAs may apply other properties as well.

Unfortunately `border-radius` isn't one of the supported properties for the `::first-line` pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

The border-radius and padding aren't supported on the first-line pseudo element.  This is about as close as I could get to what you had if I interpretted what you were looking for.  I added a line-height to make the vertical "padding", and a :before element to indent the line (left padding), but I could not figure out a neat way to do right pad only the first line. Nor could I figure out what you wanted to do with the border radius, but I put it on the caption anyway.  It currently has no discernible effect.

```
.caption:first-line
{ 
background-color:green;
line-height: 50px;
}
.caption{
    border-radius:4px;
}
.caption:before{
    content:' ';
    width:10px;
    height: 5px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use vender prefix for border radius and put first line into a separate tag like span,p etc.

```
<p class="caption">
     <span>Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text.It is used to display text in web page.</span></p>


.caption span
{ 
     background-color:green;
     -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius : 4px;
     border-radius:4px;
     padding:5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: border-radius is fully supported without vendor prefixes